# Bootstrap Accordion not working in unordered-list?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

Bootstrap accordion not working? I want other div to hide when one list-item is opened?

Here is **Code**:

```
<ul class="unstyled-list" id="accordion">
    <li class="clearfix" id="eveliidm4" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#evecolm4">
        <div class="date">10 February 2017 </div>
            <div class="place">Codart 2.0 - <span> A 48 hours coding bonanza. </span> </div> <i class="fa events3dots"></i>
    </li>
    <div class="evecol collapse" id="evecolm4">
        <p>text</p>
        <img src="images/eventm4/codart.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <li class="clearfix" id="eveliidm3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#evecolm3">
        <div class="date">19 January 2017 </div>
        <div class="place">Recruitments - <span> Freshers' core committee recruitment drive. </span> </div> <i class="fa events3dots"></i>
     </li>
     <div class="evecol collapse" id="evecolm3">
         <br>
         <img src="images/eventm3/recruitment.jpg" class="img-responsive">
     </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Bootstrap 4 Accordion Documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#accordion-example). They use divs, which may be an issue compared to your li usage. Also, you are missing a few IDs and classes that they use, such as "collapsed" and "card-block."

Below is the code that the documentation uses as an example (so not my code). I would recommend filling your information into their example and add classes to fit your CSS as needed:

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how would it achieved using `ul li` elements? is it possible?